# playing an Audio in xcode

Tags: objective-c, audio, xcode4.2

I'm trying to play an audio saved on my device and i placed it's path but it's not working
can anyone plz help?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/Luna/Library/ApplicationSupport/iPhone Simulator/5.0
/Applications/E3D65190-9DE0-4C60-A2F8-0948970A1788/Documents/Sound1.caf"];
    

NSError *error;

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: why are you hardcoding the path ... the audio exist within your project or is downloaded from somewhere?

Comment: the sound was previously recorded and saved in the document directory and it's path is saved in the database and i'm trying to play it but it's not working. HELP

Comment: You don't state what the problem is. Are the 'url', 'error', and 'audioPlayer' objects valid? Are there any errors? Generally you add this as a resource to the project and add a build phase to copy it to the app's bundle where it belongs.

Comment: The above code works when i add the audio to the supporting files but I want it to work the audio path saved in the DB !!

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSFileManager* manager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init]; 

       NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

        NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@",[manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error]);

    NSString* yourFile =[documentsDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sound1.caf"];

    if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:yourFile]) {
    NSLog(@"Audio Exists");

   }
```

The above code will output your document directory contents ..and also should log **Audio Exist** in the end...Try this and let us know what output you get

Comment: The audio already exists in the document directory but I can't retrieve it to be played. Any ideas ? Thank u for ur help.

Comment: what is the output in the console after you run the above code..(my answer)

Comment: your proposed answer was to check if there was any content in the file directory or not and as I said before the audio already exists in the file directory. My question was how to play the audio placed in the file directory but Thanks for ur time and effort shubhank.

Comment: i tried to help you and you still are trying to be smart...so -1 to you from me..well you don't have reputation as of now.. so i will do it eventually...:D